# How can I combine each element of two lists in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Say I have two arrays like this:

```
$greetings = "hello","hola","namaste"

$names = "jon","jim"
```

If I need an output like this:

```
hello jon
hola jon
namaste jon
hello jim
hola jim
namaste jim
```

What should I do?

I tried this:

```
$greetings | % { $_ + " " + $names}
```

This is just giving me output like this:

```
hello jon jim
hola jon jim
namaste jon jim
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one line:

```
$names | % { foreach($greeting in $greetings) { "$greeting $_" }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a nested loop:

```
$greetings = "hello","hola","namaste"

$names = "jon","jim"

Foreach ($name in $names)
 {
  Foreach ($greeting in $greetings)
   {
    "$greeting $name"
   }
 }
```